# Is it possible to alter .NET array allocation method?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, cuda

I'm using CUDA via P/Invoke in .NET. In CUDA, they provide a special memory allocation method, which can allocate memory on GPU while in the same time, you can access them from host (of course, unmanaged memory from .NET perspective). This is called unified memory of CUDA which blur the board between CPU and GPU memory.

So, is it possible to alter the default .NET array memory allocation method to a customized unmanaged memory allocation? In that array, I only need to store very simple primitive types such as int, double.

For example, in CUDA C++, they override the `new` operator to make that class to be seen from both CPU and GPU:

```
class Managed {
public:
  void *operator new(size_t len) {
    void *ptr;
    cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return ptr;
  }

  void operator delete(void *ptr) {
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(ptr);
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but you can deal with pointers and [``stackalloc``](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx) in an [``unsafe``](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/chfa2zb8.aspx) context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override the new operator in C# or alter the behavior of native C# arrays. But you can implement a class with the IEnumerable interface and with a []-operator. Thus your class will just act like the native arrays in C#.

I've implemented exactly this for managed memory in Cuda for my managedCuda library, here's the direct link to the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/kunzmi/managedCuda/blob/master/ManagedCUDA/CudaManagedMemoryFixedTypes.cs). I also performed a little performance test and it turned out that the cuda-managed memory is approximately as fast native-C# arrays when read and written from host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked your types, the question is, I saw you create concrete classes for different element types, why not make generic types?

Comment: You cannot use pointers with generics in C#, that's why I used tt-scripting in visual studio to create all the different classes directly. First I had another approach using generics with marshaling, but this was way too slow.